# Set calendar permissions for multiple users based on current permissions

Tags: powershell, script, exchange

I need some help with my script that I've come up with that I'm having some trouble getting it to work without giving an error or warning message.

So far I have this logic that gives "reviewer" permission to everyone's calendar  individually to a specific mail-enabled AD security group:

```
$users = Get-Mailbox | Select -ExpandProperty Alias;
Foreach ($user in $users) {Add-MailboxFolderPermission $user":\Calendar" -user *GROUP1* -accessrights Reviewer};
```

This works fine, but we create and remove user accounts often so I need the script to run as economically as possible. This logic above will check and error on each user that already has a permission set, which can take a while and adds a lot to the error logs.

What I would like is an `IF` statement, or revision to the `Select property` in the script that can check if a user has currently no permissions set to the security group, then add the permission, so if they have the permission set already it will just skip.

Something like this:

```
$users = Get-Mailbox | Select -ExpandProperty Alias;
$users2 = Get-MailboxFolderPermission -Identity $users:\Calendar -User *GROUP1* IF accessrights = NULL** ???;
Foreach ($user in **$users2**) {Add-MailboxFolderPermission $user":\Calendar" -user *GROUP1* -accessrights Reviewer};
```

Comment: What version of Exchange are you running? Not sure that it matters much but may be helpful.

Comment: Hi Pimp, it is exchange 2010 but will be moving to 2019 within this financial year. Hoping the commands will stay the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a way to use some conditional PowerShell logic with some arrays, loops, and variables to only run the `Add-MailboxFolderPermission` command if the "Group Name" does not already have access. I've also included some supporting resources for further reading on the components of the logic.

```
$gName = "GROUP1";
$accounts = (Get-Mailbox | Select -ExpandProperty Alias);

$accounts | % {
    $a = $_;
    $z = (Get-MailboxFolderPermission -Identity $a":\Calendar");
    $y = ($z | %{$_.User.DisplayName});
    If($y -notcontains $gName){Add-MailboxFolderPermission $a":\Calendar" -user $gName -accessrights Reviewer};
    };
```

---

### Supporting Resources

- [ForEach-Object](https://ss64.com/ps/foreach-object.html)

  > Standard [Aliases](https://ss64.com/ps/get-alias.html) for Foreach-Object: the '`%`' symbol, ForEach
- [If](https://ss64.com/ps/if.html)
- [Comparison Operators](https://ss64.com/ps/syntax-compare.html)
- [Arrays](https://ss64.com/ps/syntax-arrays.html)

Comment: @C-Burg .... As you can see within the `$accounts` loop the `$y` variable is a looped over `array` set data type. So within the `If()` function you can use the `-notcontains` comparison operator to only run the `Add-MailboxFolderPermission` command if the `$y` array does NOT contain the security "group" name or whatever. Those are the keys to the logic I think.

Comment: You are definitely on another level for just being able to build these scripts like that. I'm learning a lot and will go through those supporting resources as well thanks! I tried the script and it adds the permission to users that do not have the permission set, but it will give an error for each user that has.

Comment: So somehow it is still checking each user, adding the permission - error "Add-MailboxFolderPermission : An existing permission entry was found for user: GROUP1." and then go on to the next one.

Comment: You are a legend, cheers bud, worked a charm.